# Unable to insert data into SQlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am an Beginner in android and i am facing problem in insertion of data into table.The question has been asked many times but i am unable understand the root of the problem and its solution.

```
public long insertRegisterData(RegisterData data) throws SQLException {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("u_name", data.getU_name());
    cv.put("u_address", data.getU_address());
    cv.put("tel_office", data.getTel_office());
    cv.put("tel_resi", data.getTel_resi());
    cv.put("tel_req", data.getTel_req());
    cv.put("tel_fax", data.getTel_fax());
    cv.put("dateSanad", data.getDateSanad());
    cv.put("memBarCounWelfare", data.getMemBarCounWelfare());
    cv.put("prof_tax", data.getProf_tax());
    cv.put("pan", data.getPan());
    cv.put("drivingPolicyNo", data.getDrivingPolicyNo());
    cv.put("drivingPolicyDue", data.getDrivingPolicyDue());
    cv.put("bankAcc", data.getBankAcc());
    cv.put("passport", data.getPassport());
    cv.put("blood", data.getBlood());
    cv.put("docName", data.getDocName());
    cv.put("docPhone", data.getDocPhone());
    cv.put("docAddress", data.getDocAddress());

    System.out.println("Comntent vlaues     " + cv.get("u_name"));
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert("Registration1", null, cv);

}



public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create table newRecord(prev_date  text,CaseName text,caseNo                                   Text,forParty text,againstParty text,stages text)");
    db.execSQL("Create table Registration1(u_name text,u_address text,tel_office text,tel_resi text,tel_req text,tel_fax text,dateSanad text,memBarCounWelfare text,prof_tax text,pan text,drivingPolicyNo text,drivingPolicyDue text,bankAcc text,passport text,blood text,docName text,docPhone text,docAddress text)");
}
```

In the printstackTrace

```
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622): Error inserting docName=H memBarCounWelfare=Download  prof_tax=D drivingPolicyNo=X docAddress=sachin tel_req=Dd blood=G tel_resi=D dateSanad=D tel_office= pan=null drivingPolicyDue=Dddsdfdssd dfg d tel_fax=D u_address=s bankAcc=D docPhone=99 passport=D u_name=S
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Registration1: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Registration1(docName, memBarCounWelfare, prof_tax, drivingPolicyNo, docAddress, tel_req, blood, tel_resi, dateSanad, tel_office, pan, drivingPolicyDue, tel_fax, u_address, bankAcc, docPhone, passport, u_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at com.database.SQLiteAdapter.insertRegisterData(SQLiteAdapter.java:116)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at com.diary.OneTimePassword$1.onClick(OneTimePassword.java:107)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-18 02:08:35.362: E/Database(3622):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: "no such table: Registration1", create the table first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your table *Registration1* does not exist. The method `onCreate` is called if the database does not exist, this means that your database was created the first time you ran your program, but if later you added the second table *Registration1* the table will NOT be created.

You need to override `onUpgrade` in you database Helper class (you could simply delete the tables and call onCreate()), and also next time you run you're program you need to increase the version number in the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor.
When you run your program, the runtime compares the version you're specifying against the version already in storage, and if they differ, the runtime calls `onUpgrade`.

EDIT:
Here are two examples, the first one alters the existing table. Te second example recreates the table (deleting all previous data).

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    if (oldVersion<2)
    {
        // Example of altering the table
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + myTable + " ADD COLUMN " + newColumn + " int;");
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // Delete and create table
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + myTable + " ;");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: can u suggest how to create table in onupgrade()?

Comment: @SupriyoBhattacherjee I added two examples

Comment: don't you mean `drop table` ?

Comment: @Merlevede i want to create another table...you were right about the issue.i need to create the other table in onUpgrade method

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the error can be found here:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: **no such table: Registration1**: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Registration1(docName, memBarCounWelfare, prof_tax, drivingPolicyNo, docAddress, tel_req, blood, tel_resi, dateSanad, tel_office, pan, drivingPolicyDue, tel_fax, u_address, bankAcc, docPhone, passport, u_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Your `CREATE TABLE` statement for `Registration1` is either failing or is not being called.  You can try setting a breakpoint or inserting a log statement in `onCreate()` and make sure you're getting there.  You can also surround the `execSQL()` calls with `try / catch (SQLException e)` and see if there's a `SQLException` being thrown.